# sql big clob convert rawtohex gives error ORA-06502

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hello guys I have one clob table with 8000bytes I want to convert it to rawtohex using

rawtohex(TO_CHAR(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(a.COMMENTS, 8000, 1))) but it throws
character string buffer too small error any idea to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

If your `maximum_string_size` is set to `standard`, then the maximum raw size is 2000 bytes and your 8000 byte (character?) CLOB is too big for that. You should consider that your CLOB might have multibyte characters and 1 character != 1 byte.

If you are absolutely sure your CLOB contains only ASCII characters, you might be able to get away with something like this in PL/SQL:

```
i := 1;
while i < length(l_clob) loop
    l_chunk := dbms_lob.substr( l_clob, 2000, i );
    l_raw_chunk := utl_raw.cast_to_raw( my_chunk );
    l_hex := l_hex || rawtohex( l_raw_chunk );
    i := i + 2000;
end loop;
```

You could also use `dbms_lob.convertoblob` to convert your CLOB to a BLOB, use `dbms_lob.substr` to turn that BLOB into chunks of RAWs, then use `rawtohex` on those. You don't say what you're really trying to do, so I'm not sure I can be more specific.

Edit:

If you are just trying to find instances where `0x2014` or `0xC296` occur, you might be better off with something like this:

```
select * 
  from mytable a
 where dbms_lob.instr( a.comments, hextoraw( '2014' )) > 0
```

Comment: hi thank you for your reply. I am trying to achieve the following  
select * from table
    where 
    
    rawtohex(dbms_lob.substr(column, 8000,1 )) like '%2014%'
How can achive that with your code above?

Comment: Are you looking for the string "2014" in your CLOB?

Comment: I am converting the string into hexcode through rawtohex and looking for 2014 hexcode. Due to my column is CLOB it can't be parsed into hextoraw for that reason I have to convert CLOB to varchar

Comment: So in hex, 0x2014 is two bytes and is a space character followed by the Device Control 4 character, which I literally just had to look up to find out what that is. Are you sure that's what you're trying to do? Can you explain why you're converting this CLOB to hex?

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply again, In  my database I have one CLOB field that has some wrong characters showing as [], after long search I find out that these characters is hex 2014 and C296 for that reason I am trying to convert clob to hex throw dbms_lob.substr

Comment: OK, so you really are looking for those byte sequences. My guess is a character set conversion issue at some point? If you really do want to convert them to BLOBs, you'll probably need a stored function to do that. If you just want to find them, try the updated answer above.

Comment: hello I think the problem is inside update I get numeric or value error: character string buffer too small.          UPDATE table1 SET coll1 =  REPLACE(coll1,  UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(HEXTORAW('C296')), '-');

Comment: I think you might be in luck, C296 is actually a valid Unicode code point U+0096, so you can do `replace(col1, unistr('\0096'), '-' )`. You might be able to do the same with `unistr('\0020\0014')`, I'm not sure.

Comment: select * 
  from mytable a
 where dbms_lob.instr( a.comments, hextoraw( '2014' )) > 0  this is not working my CLOB  max LENGTH value is 9816 so If i try to hextoraw 9816*4 = 39.264 so it gives numeric error. I try to split to smaller with ex hextoraw(dbms.substring(col,500,1)).... hextoraw(dbms.substring(col,1000,9500); but also I get numeric error any idea to find the wrong COLB data and replace it with such a big length?

Comment: I don't think you're using `hextoraw` correctly. It takes a hexadecimal number and converts it to bytes, so if you do `hextoraw('41')` it will return a 1-byte raw containing 'A' or 0x41. I doubt your CLOB is containing a string of hex codes. SQL is not going to cut it. I don't see any way you're doing this outside of PL/SQL.

Comment: This is working perfect select * 
  from mytable a
 where dbms_lob.instr( a.comments, unistr('\0096')) > 0 . Thank you a lot!